# C# Values resetting after breaking out of a switch case

Tags: c#

I am trying to take user input and then use that input to calculate a chart, but every time i set the value, the value resets back to the initial value as zero. I know this because the method `StraightLineDepreciation()` is returning a message that is telling me I haven't entered a number, that returns only when the values are 0, thats what the initial values are. It seems like it resets after breaking out of the switch loop. Here is my program.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        double amount = 0;
        int years = 0;
        char menuItem;
        Console.WriteLine("This program computes depreciation tables using various methods of depreciation");
        menuItem = GetMenuChoice();
        while (menuItem != 'Q')
        {
            ProcessMenuItem(menuItem,amount,years);
            menuItem = GetMenuChoice();
        }           
        Console.WriteLine("Goodbye!");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }



    static void ProcessMenuItem(char menuItem, double amount, int years)
    {
        switch (menuItem)
        {
            case 'A':
                ProcessSetValues(ref amount, ref years);
                Console.WriteLine("{0} {1}", amount, years);
                break;
            case 'B':
                StraightLineDepreciation( amount, years);
                break;
            case 'C':
                break;
            case 'D':
                break;
        }
    }
    static void ProcessSetValues(ref double amount, ref int years)
    {
        amount = GetPositiveDouble("How much money is to be depreciated?");
        years = GetPositiveInteger("Over how many years");
        return;

    }
    static void StraightLineDepreciation( double amount,  int years)
    {
        if(amount != 0 && years != 0)
        {
            amount = amount / years;
            Console.WriteLine("Year    Depreciation");
            Console.WriteLine("---- ---------------");
            for (int counter = 0; counter < years; counter++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("    {0,+6}{1}", amount, years);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("You have not entered any values for the amount and years.");
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you make sure you make all occurrences of your methods pass `ref`  because i think that is the problem:

```
ProcessMenuItem(ref menuItem,ref amount,ref years);
StraightLineDepreciation( ref amount, ref years);
```

Or simply make a wrapper class and pass the reference type around instead of using value types.

```
class DepreciationTracker
{
    double amount;
    int years;
}

ProcessMenuItem( DepreciationTracker obj)
{
     //modify obj
}
StraightLineDepreciation( DepreciationTracker obj)
{
     //modify obj
}
```

Also would recommend a primer on [Value vs Reference Types](http://www.albahari.com/valuevsreftypes.aspx).

Comment: would it also work if i just removed all of my ref's

Comment: @JeremyCortez If you use classes then Yes, classes are Reference Types but for elementary value types like int, double, struct, etc you cannot do away without the `ref`.